# Maven dependencies between my own modules only

Tags: dependencies, maven-3

I need something that seems to me not so specific and that should exist in Maven, but I can't find a way to get it and I'm therefore asking me if it exists...

I want to know the dependencies between my own modules only, so between modules written by me and sharing a similar groupid.
Is it possible with Maven, or not ? And if it is possible (as I hope), how can I do it ?

Thank you,

Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in fact, I found what I searched.
By using the command :

```
dependency:list -DincludeGroupIds=my.groupid
```

I am able to get my own dependency list.
It is not really easy to read and use, but it does the minimal job.

Seb